# Which model selection criteria with log posterior odds and model rank?

Tags: r, bayesian, model-selection, posterior

I am learning Bayesian Statistics with this course [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bayesian/peer/W6yxq/data-analysis-project). I use the Bayesian Sampling package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BAS/vignettes/BAS-vignette.html) and I got the following plot with R such that

```
library(BAS)
test <- BAS::bas.lm(data=mtcars, formula = mpg ~ ., prior = "JZS"); 
image(test, rotate=FALSE)
```

[image]

I guess that posterior odds can be calculated from log posterior odds of BAS with formula `e^{log posterior odd}` where I assume that log is a natural logarithm. Even though posterior probabilities increase, the problem is that the model rank increases as well causing overfitting.

Suppose the model with log posterior odds equal to 8. So has this model only 0.0003354~0.03%~exp(-8.0) regression power (not prediction power)?

So

**How can I select a model based on model rank and log posterior odds? Which model selection criteria to use?**